# Colpitts oscillator startup problem

Tags: operational-amplifier, oscillator

I use the following Colpitts oscillator schematic and I always need to put the scope probe on the inverting input of the opamp to make it start. Otherwise I get a DC voltage and no oscillations.

Do you have any idea about what I can do to to have a reliable startup at powerup ?

Thanks.

[image: colpitts oscillator]

Answer (score 3):

Try reading [this](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/oscillator/colpitts.html) tutorial: -

[image]

Note the use of R3 to prevent the op-amp output being directly loaded by one of the capacitors. Theoretically you have to have some phase shift between output and first capacitor and therefore you need a resistor.

Note also that the gain in your circuit is far too high.

I'm not ruling out anything else too.

Comment: Yes - I agree to Andy`s recommendation regarding R3. The BJT acts as a current source - in contrast to an opamp which is a voltage source. For this reason an opamp based Colpitt oscullator needs such a resistor R3.

Answer (score 0):

Given that this is an old question, I will provide another answer just for reference of future generations. As a fellow electronics student, I found the following simple Falstad circuit to be helpful in understanding Colpitts Oscillator with an op-amp:

[image]

- [See this Falstad circuit simulation](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$+1+0.000005+3.59933188356284+40+5+43%0Aa+112+96+224+96+0+15+-15+1000000%0Aw+32+208+112+208+0%0Al+112+208+240+208+0+0.1+-0.16288964577354803%0Aw+240+208+288+208+0%0Aw+288+208+288+304+0%0Aw+32+208+32+336+0%0Aw+32+336+64+336+0%0Ac+64+336+128+336+0+0.00001+-12.513289421151928%0Ac+224+336+272+336+0+0.00001+-12.494899545068407%0Aw+288+304+288+336+0%0Aw+288+336+272+336+0%0Aw+224+336+128+336+0%0Ag+128+336+128+384+0%0Aw+32+208+32+176+0%0Ag+112+112+112+144+0%0Ar+224+32+112+32+0+1000000%0Aw+112+32+112+80+0%0Aw+288+96+288+208+0%0Ar+224+96+288+96+0+1000%0Ar+112+80+32+80+0+47000%0Aw+32+80+32+176+0%0Aw+288+208+384+208+0%0Aw+224+32+224+96+0%0Ao+21+64+0+551+20+0.00009765625+0+-1%0A)

Comment: So your answer is that s/he should add a 1kΩ resistor at the output of the op-amp?