# Simulation problem

Tags: circuit-design, oscillator, simulation, ads

I'm a new user to ADS (Advanced System design). I'm trying to design a discrete Colpitt oscillator at 100 MHz in ADS.
Here's my schematic:
[image]

Now I wanna check if my circuit works properly. I watched and read some tutorial but it seems like a lot of new stuff to me.
Can anyone help me to solve the problem?

Comment: your circuit won't work! place the inductor between collector and Vcc

Comment: Yes you’re right it’s a big mistake. Thank you!

Comment: By the way do you know how to use ADS? I’m wondering which type of simulation I should use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problems in coloured boxes: -

[image]

- \$\color{red}{RED}\$ box - no joining junction at cross over point hence transistor gets no bias
- \$\color{blue}{BLUE}\$ box - inductor passes DC freely and hence connects collector to ground
- \$\color{purple}{PURPLE}\$ box lower - Move C4 into vacant space in upper purple box and replace C4 with a short
- \$\color{purple}{PURPLE}\$ box upper - Move C4 into that position

Comment: thank you! By the way, do you know how to use ADS? Which type of simulation should I use?

Comment: Sorry I don’t know how to use it. I use micro cap 12. Did the fix proposals work? BTW if you are looking for a very good sim with tons of library parts, micro cap is now free (as in free beer and just as tasty). Highly recommended.

Comment: yes it helped. Actually I referenced this 100 MHz CB Colpitt Oscillator from the book Discrete oscillator design, Linear, Nonlinear, Transient and Noise Domains by Randall Rhea. Here's the schematic in the book https://drive.google.com/file/d/1N_f_R-uc-O8s287DE5zs4xJFunk1mlHi/view?usp=sharing I don't understand the meaning of CP1, port 1 and port 2. I tried to edit the circuit and made the above mistake. Have you got any idea what those things mean?

Comment: No, I have no idea but I wouldn’t worry.

Comment: I've just read your answer to this question about opamp-based Colpitt oscillator https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/196274/colpitts-oscillator-startup-problem?fbclid=IwAR3M3y5T5wdPrZ1zw78EYEbOBG9S-AYpbQCJHVFOX4gOjbBtrHUnqlp2DN8. I'm trying to design an oscillator with some specs so I'm wondering if the value of R3 affects the calculations such as the gain of the opamp amplifier block?

Comment: Sorry I can't comment directly to that post because I don't have enough reputations

Comment: @HenryNguyen [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/355018/colpitts-oscillators-capacitors/355062#355062) derives the equations for the colpitts oscillator and the resistor in question cancels out of the equation (but that resistor is needed).

Comment: Do you mean the equations for the Colpitts oscillator are wrong if I put a resistor at the output of the amplifier? I'm trying to design a 100 MHz Colpitts oscillator and It would be great if you could give me a educational answer.

Comment: @HenryNguyen I think you should raise this as a new question because others will likely want to contribute. Firstly though, go through a few questions using the search bar above to see if anyone has already answered this.